# Loading the Level in Unity is not working properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am new to game design and I am using unity.
I used the following code -

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class player_collisions : MonoBehaviour
{

private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision col)

{
    if(col.gameObject.tag == "Enemy")
    { PlayerDies(); }
}
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider trig)
{
    if (trig.gameObject.tag == "Coin")
    {
        //increase coin collection
        //increase audio
        Data_Management.dataManagement.coinsCollected++;
        Destroy(trig.gameObject);
    }

}

void PlayerDies()
{           SceneManager.LoadScene("main");
}

}
```

However, when my main scene is loaded, it looks different...
Please HELP!

[actual scene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUJbV.png)
[after loadscene](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Z1x1.png)``

Comment: youve hidden the hierarchy inside the newly loaded "main" scene, can you add a picture of that?

Comment: it just looks like the normal lighting change to me

Answer (score 0):

[This is a known behavior for the unity editor](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1264278/unity-5-directional-light-problem-please-help.html)

Make sure it looks ok on a normal build and not when playing from the editor. If it looks ok, you can fix it by following the instructions I linked.